# Importing js with Laravel Mix

Tags: ecmascript-6, laravel-mix

I can't see to import js files with laravel-mix in the build process.  I get module not found errors for every file I am importing into my main.js file.

I have a folder structure like

```
src
--resources
----js
------main.js
----views
------blocks
--------slider
-----------slider.js
```

In my main js file I import like the following

```
import slider from '../veiws/blocks/slider/slider.js';
```

My laravel mix file looks like this.

```
mix.js('src/resources/js/main.js', 'src/public/js')
```

What else do I need to make this work.

Comment: I guess you made a typo: `'../veiws/`?

Comment: omg @Jeffrey thankyou, Can't believe tis was the problem.  Been staring at this forever

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to see here guys/gals.  This works correctly if you don't have a typo like me.